# Mongodb seems to load data twice. Not sure why and not sure if I'm loading mongodb right

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, duplicates, load

I'm trying to get my flask app to load a csv file into mongodb and then display the data back. For some reason, somewhere within my app the app the data gets duplicated. Don't really know how to debug it and not sure if I'm setting up the data load in the right place in the first place. Any advice would be appreciated. Relevant code is below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

import io
import csv
import json
import ast

app = Flask(__name__)
client = MongoClient("mongodb://db:27017")
db = client.projectDB
""" 
HELPER FUNCTIONS
"""

def loadDB():
    print("Initializing mongodb client")
    
    db_collection = db['recipe_data']
    #Uniqueness constraint for name, not necessary?
    # db_collection.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
    if db_collection.count() == 0:
        recipes = db_collection.recipes
        loaded_recipes_list = loadRecipes()
        for recipe in loaded_recipes_list:
            recipes.insert_one(recipe)
    print("Database loaded successfully!")

def loadRecipes():
    recipe_data = []

    #Load recipes
    csv_file = "./recipes_short.csv"
    rows = io.open(csv_file, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    reader = csv.reader(rows)
    for data in reader:
        recipe = {}
        recipe['name'] = data[0]
        recipe['id'] = data[1]
        recipe['minutes'] = data[2]
        recipe['contributor_id'] = data[3]
        recipe['submitted'] = data[4]
        recipe['tags'] = data[5].lstrip('[').rstrip(']').replace("'", "").split(',')
        recipe['n_steps'] = data[6].lstrip('[').rstrip(']').replace("'", "").split(',')
        recipe['steps'] = data[7]
        recipe['description'] = data[8].lstrip('[').rstrip(']').replace("'", "").split(',')
        recipe['ingredients'] = data[9]
        recipe['n_ingredients'] = data[10].lstrip('[').rstrip(']').replace("'", "").split(',')
        recipe_data.append(recipe)
    print(recipe_data)
    return recipe_data

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loadDB()
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: To add to this, I am deploying the app with docker and the flask folder is a shared mount. I've noticed that whenever I change and save the flask code, it creates even more duplicates. I'm guessing this is normal but it might be a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are running flask with `debug=True`. This will reload the file when starting and therefore will run your data loader twice.

If you take the flag off (which you should do in production anyway), it will not reload.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think this would be fixed if I loaded mongodb data in the docker image right after creation?

Comment: If you're worreid about duplicate data it might be easier to change yout inserts to `update_one()` with a filter on recipe_id and `upsert=True`